# How does one deal with categorical labels in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, categorical-data, tf.data.dataset

How does one transform (e.g., one-hot encode, index, bucketize, embed, etc.) labels natively in TensorFlow? `tf.feature_column` is the preferred way for features, but what about the labels (i.e., targets)? Those too may often need to be transformed and treated as a layer in the overall Keras pipeline. The problem is that `tf.feature_column` only acts on the features, not the labels.

Consider for example a CSV

```
F1     F2    T 
3.7    2.0   A
1.7    3.5   B
6.0    6.6   A
0.7    3.2   A
```

where `F1` and `F2` are the features and `T` the target. I'd then naturally call `make_csv_dataset(..., label_name='T')` to generate my dataset. But then how do I transform the targets so that all data processing is neatly wrapped in a `Dense` layer?

Has the `tf.data` team at TensorFlow overlooked the fact that labels are often categorical and therefore need to be transformed?

**EDIT**: I would like to avoid any use of pandas since it's not scalable, hence my emphasis on the "native" tools of `tf.data` (e.g., `make_csv_dataset()` or otherwise).

Comment: For labels you may use: `tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y)`

Comment: Have you resolved your issue? I'm ending up in this scenario too often and I'm looking for a way to perform label encoding with tf.data or some scalable way. I also want to avoid pandas or one hot encoding as much as possible as this does not scale. Currently have to do it at data set building stage (with spark, Flink...)

Answer (score 2):

In this case you got 2 options:

1. convert to class label index then use sparse categorical cross entropy
2. transform the class label index to one hot encoding - in this case you have to use categorical cross entropy loss

EDIT:
Note the function to one hot encode the classes

```py
In [14]: @tf.function
    ...: def map_labels(feature, target):
    ...:     return feature, tf.one_hot(target, 2) # number of classes = 2
```

You can add the dataset as such if you are using tf dataset api

```py
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: import tensorflow as tf
2021-08-03 15:58:01.546181: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame({
   ...:     'F1': [20 ,30 ,40 ,60],
   ...:     'F2': [10, 50, 300, 300],
   ...:     'label': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B']
   ...:     })
In [8]: df['label'] = df['label'].replace({'A': 0, 'B': 1})
In [12]: dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((df.iloc[:, :-1], df.iloc[:, -1]))

In [13]: dataset = dataset.shuffle(len(dataset)).map(map_labels).batch(20)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of how you'd do it on the *labels*, though. The problem with feature columns is that they only act on features, not labels. I'd like to use the native `tf.data`, not the less-scalable pandas data frames.

Comment: i have made adjustment o my answer but u can easily adapt my answer

Comment: Thanks... But the point is that I want to avoid pandas altogether as it's not scalable. (If it were for using pandas all of this would have been a non-issue, hence my emphasis on using solely `tf.data` with, e.g., `make_csv_dataset()`.)